# Tablet on Emulator doesn't pickup proper tablet specific resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm working on an app where there are tablet resources and regular phone resources.
My layouts are in
**layout**
and
**layout-sw600dp**

These files **load properly** depending on their width on **actual devices but not on the emulator**.

To clarify, layout/main_activity will load on a Nexus 5 device and layout-sw600dp/main_activity will load on a Nexus 7 device. However, when I create these two devices on the emulator, both emulations will pickup the phone layout. This is happening on the newest iMac 27" with android's default emulator. I tried pixel density to be 1dp to 3px but I cannot see the screen to be able to determine if this works. Even if it did, I could only see 1/6th of the emulated screen so that wasn't useful.

If there's any missing info you need, please comment below.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!